# Working with "multidimensional" "dynamic arrays" in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to execute the following code. Though the task is trivial, I am getting a segmentation fault.

The aim of the code snippet betlow is to create a multi dimensional array of maximum row size 4 and column size 33. Then after creation, it should set the contents of all the rows as 0, followed by a `'\0'` character. Then in the end, it should display the output on the `stdout`.

Although I am not new to programming, I keep on getting similar errors, so if possible please explain me how can I avoid such mistakes in the future.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int i,j,k,x,y;
        char** arr;
        arr = (char**) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                arr[i] = (char*) malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
                memset(arr,0,8);
                arr[i][8] = '\0';
        }
        for ( j = 0; j<4; j++) {
                puts(arr[j]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Casting `malloc` is generally wrong, as it can potentially hide errors. ([Relevant reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

Comment: The thing you are building here is often called a "ragged array" or "jagged array" and it is different from a vanilla two dimensional array such as you can declare with `char arr[33][4]`; Ragged arrays are only one of several solutions to the problem of dynamic multidimensional arrays in c.

Comment: You also need to free() the memory blocks allocated with malloc(). Add for(j=0;j<4;++j)free(arr[j]);free(arr); before return 0;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're `memset`ing the wrong pointer.

Instead of:

```
memset(arr,0,8);
```

you want:

```
memset(arr[i],0,8);
```

So you're off by one level of indirection.

---

As pointed out in the comments, here are some optimizations:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char*) malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
    memset(arr[i],0,9);
}
```

or

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char*) calloc(9, sizeof(char));
}
```

Note that the cast to `char*` isn't necessary in C.

---

If you wanted to the character `'0'` instead of the null-character, then you should go with this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char*) malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
    memset(arr[i],'0',8);
    arr[i][8] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: +1: and the code should be using `memset(arr[i], '\0', 9);` so that the separate assignment of the extra 0 byte is not needed.

Comment: Or just use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` and forget about it :)

Comment: +1 for addressing the seg-fault; but from the description, I think the OP *might* actually need `memset(arr[i],'0',8)` (setting each element to a length-eight null-terminated string of zeroes).

Comment: @ruakh It could be, it's not entirely clear if the OP wants '\0' or '0'.

Comment: The OP wants to fill the string with '0', printing '\0' would not produce any output.

Answer (score 1):

```
memset(arr,0,8);
```

is the issue, you are clearing the array of pointers

try:

```
memset(arr[i], '0', 8);
```

assuming you want to fill the string with zeros

Answer (score 0):

in the for loop I think you have an logical error:

```
memset(arr[i],0,8);
```

you also don't need to set this:

```
arr[i][8] = '\0';
```

instead you could do this:

```
memset(arr[i],0,9);
```

the '\0' character is nothing different then 0.